# Include an external .md file in a docblock?

Tags: doxygen

There are doxygen commands @include, @htmlinclude, @verbinclude and the rest of the family. Each of them is equivalent to inlcuding the file inline **and surrounding it with a pair of start and end tags** like @code, @htmlonly, @verbatim etc.

For the life of me, I cannot find the doxygen command equivalent to **just** pasting a markdown file into the docblock **without** surrounding it with any tags that modify the interpretation of the included fragment.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: It's been a year, did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately the answer is negative. It simply cannot be done, full stop.

Comment: How unfortunate.  Thanks for the quick reply